# Insert Chinese characters in MySql database using Java

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

In my local environment it works fine, in my production environment, it doesn't.

I've been reading a lot of answers on the internet. It seems I didn't get the answer I'm looking for.

I can read Chinese characters from the database. When I write Chinese characters to the database they turn up like `'???'`. When I query the database to find a Chinese entry in the database, the result set is empty.

I use `Java` for development, `jdk 1.6`. MySQL server: 5.0.91

My web application has `utf-8` in the header of the web pages. In my servlets I set character encoding to `utf-8.` My tables and the columns in my tables use `utf8_general_ci`.

I added `?useUnicode=yes&characterEncoding=UTF-8` to the URL of my database. I added `SET NAMES 'UTF8' COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci'` before I do a query.

```
Character_set_connection = utf8
```

I noticed that on the production server, the `character_set_server = latin1.` However, when I changed `character_set_server` in my local environment to `latin1`, I could still insert Chinese characters.

In my production environment, they tell me that others don't have any problem.

I think I pretty much covered what has been suggested by many. Anyone any idea as to what else could be the problem?

Update: quick temporary fix for those who need it, in the absence of a good solution.

To insert the variable `name` in the database:

Create a new column `name_as_bytes` using datatype `varbinary()`

Convert `name` to a bytes array
`byte[] nameAsBytes = name.getBytes("UTF-8");`

Insert `nameAsBytes` in `name_as_bytes` in the database

Copy the `name_as_bytes` column to the `name` column, using convert() function

```
update myTable set name = CONVERT(nameAsBytes USING utf8) where ID = id;
```

With the extra query being performed, and the extra column added, this is not an ideal solution, but it helps to get your website going while looking for a solution.

Comment: Did you try to debug it step by step and check if the string you send to the database has the proper chinese charcter? If you pass the strings around and use them in streams etc the streams must also be made with UTF8 and if you miss that sometimes during manipulation you lose the characters

Comment: When I debug step my step in my local environment, the strings all show up with proper Chinese characters, and they get inserted in the database as Chinese characters.

Comment: I don't know how to debug step by step in my production environment though, I don't have my own server. I used logback to write the strings to an output file just before I insert them in the database, and they show up fine in the output file. To make sure I am sending utf-8 encoded strings I tried something like: String nameAsUtf8 = new String(name.getBytes("UTF-8"), Charset.UTF-8), where name is the string that I want to insert in the database. No luck with that either.

Answer (score 1):

I finally solved this problem by two operations.
1. to do with database, create table/database with character set such as `CREATE DATABASE name CHARACTER SET 'utf8mb4';`
2. to do with JDBC, add `characterEncoding` and `useUnicode` properties after the connection url such as `jdbc:mysql://ip/dbname?useUnicode=yes&characterEncoding=UTF-8` 

P.S. using `utf8mb4` rather than `utf8` because the latter one support less chinese characters.